# Uncaught Exception error

Tags: android

Can anyone explain why I am getting a `NullPointerException` for the below code?
I want to do something with the text in my `TextView`:

```
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    context=this;
    String present_value_string = tv.getText().toString();
```

**XML of TextView**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="@string/player_score" />
```

**res/layout/strings.xml**

```
<string name="player_score">0</string>
```

Comment: where do you initialize textview in activity?

Comment: You need to make sure that setContentView is called before you call findViewById

Comment: Did You set content view before provided code part?

Comment: please post some more code and log cat as well

Comment: post your whole `onCreate()` method.

Comment: `strings.xml` must be under `res/values/` folder wile you say you have `res/layout/strings.xml`

Comment: `res/layout/strings.xml` ??? are you serious, your `string.xml` is inside your `layout` folder ?

Comment: Sorry, it is res/values/strings.xml Typo

Answer (score 0):

Use need to do

```
tv.settext("0");
```

before

```
String present_value_string = tv.getText().toString();
```

because no value is asign to text and didn't pick the string value

Answer (score 0):

In general, in such cases you add logging:

```
void myFunc()  {
    // ...
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Log.d("~~~~","\n\n\n\n~~~~ tv="+tv);
    context=this;
Log.d("~~~~","~~~~ tv.getText()="+tv.getText());
    String present_value_string = tv.getText().toString();
    //...
}
```

The `\n\n\n` help you locate the relevant part in the log (but do not forget to remove logging with `\n`'s immediately after you locate the problem).

The missing indent makes it easy to delete the logs later.

I hope you know how to use `adb logcat`.